# How would one rewrite the url to remove the aspx extension and also redirect a trailing slash?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, url-rewriting, seo

I want to remove the aspx extension for clean urls, and also redirect when a trailing slash is used.

In my web.config file:

```
<!-- Rewrite, adding extension -->
<rule name="add aspx">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
<!-- Removes trailing slash after rewrite -->
<rule name="remove trailing slash after rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/.aspx$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

So, basically if one requests the url "mysite/mypage", this will have the aspx extension added on and work okay, and when one requests "mysite/mypage/", they get redirected to "mysite/mypage".

My solution seems to work, but is there a more efficient way to do it with just a rewrite and not a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that order matters, so I did the following: first redirect the trailing slash, then do the rewrite.

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Add aspx">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

This seems to be the best way, unless someone knows a better one.